# Why does Spring Boot app start when two @Bean methods are present for restTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this dependency:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And I have this config:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder
            .setConnectTimeout(ofMillis(3000))
            .setReadTimeout(ofMillis(3000))
            .build();
    }
}
```

I wonder why Spring does not fail on start. It never inits first restTemplate but inits second one. I would expect Spring to fail.

Comment: Maybe because your class AppConfig does not have a @Configuration annotation and is therefore not picked during component scanning?

Comment: It does and the application starts and uses RestTemplate to perform queries.

Comment: It isn't redis but just `RestTemplate` and it should fail because? The last one overrides the first one (because of the same name) so a request for a `RestTemplate` will call the second method (as that overrides the first one). This is allowed in a single config class. I would expect it to fail if this would have been in 2 different classes. If this fails in 2.1.9 and/or 2.0 then it might be a regression but I doubt it.

Comment: Indeed, it is not about redis. it is not even important whether it is restTemplate or other bean. If you provide two methods with same name but different parameters somehow one is picked up while another one is ignored. But also I see if I introduce 3d parametrised method with the same name it will fail.

Comment: And if you add more madness and add 3rd bean like this:
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder, AppProperties appProperties) {

Consider AppProperties is another bean declared somewhere else. Then it will use 3rd method only to instantiate RestTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid case, you are defining two bean definitions with same `name` of same bean, then the last bean defined will replace then first one bean defined.

If you want to an exception is thrown when two beans are defined by same name then you can configure by using [setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(boolean allowBeanDefinitionOverriding)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html#setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding-boolean-) method from `DefaultListableBeanFactory` is who overrides whether it should be allowed to override bean definitions by registering a different definition with the same name.

Comment: One more interesting finding is if I separate two beans into two different configs it will fail. When they are in the same config it will pick up a bean with highest number of arguments in the method.